# Why is the defining condition for extremal surfaces $K_a=0$

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

I'd been trying to find the conditions to define the extremal surfaces. I have stumbled upon https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.08423 here, the condition they use is the vanishing of mean curvature. 
My question are:

- (a) How to derive that condition, i.e. $K_a=0$?
- (b) What are the other ways to impose the extremal condition, more specifically the condition of being maximal on the surface.
- (c) The differential geometry references sources where they treat the same math as in the above cited reference.

PS. I am aware of how the extremal surfaces are defined as bulk probes in the context of holographic study of entanglement entropy and quantum complexity in terms of the variational principle. But I want to define them along the lines of the above cited reference, i.e. in terms of the second fundamental form.

Comment: Section 4.2.1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.08012 discusses this derivation.  You could also look at the paper by Jim Simons (ref [41] in the linked article) for some math literature on this condition.  There's a good chance most standard texts on differential geometry will also contain the derivation, since I think it fairly standard.

Comment: Thanks, Asperanz.

Comment: This article has all the information you’re looking for https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.02297.